# Fermat's little Theorem Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a clojure function for Fermat's little theorem.

I am breaking the problem down and trying to complete it step by step.

The first thing I want to write is the code to answer this part of my problem:

Given a number n, pick a random number a that is less than n. Compute the remainder of a^n modulo n.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
  (defn exp [a n]
  (reduce * (repeat n a)))

(mod (exp 3 5) 5)
```

This seems to work correctly and can test for prime numbers. However I now want to put this inside a function and get a to be selected at random. Is there a simple way of getting random integers in clojure?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the [`rand-int`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rand-int) function:

```
(defn rand-mod [n]
  (mod (exp (rand-int n) n) n))
```

Comment: Hi, that rand-int is perfect, however to test using Fermat's Little Theorem I need to know what the integer as I need to compare the answer to it. Is there anyway to print out the integer when testing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @benjano Just use a let binding to bind the random number, print the number, then return the result of the equation. Of course you could always create a wrapper function that prints out the result, then returns the random number.

Comment: @benjano A nice concise version: `(defn rand-int-p [n] (doto (rand-int n) println))`. Then just remove the "-p" to switch to the non-printing version. Note, printing from inside of a non-procedure function is usually a bad idea since not every use of the function will necessarily require printing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that randomly select a number, compute the answer using your `exp` function, and return both values as a vector:

```
(defn rand-mod [n]
  (let [a (rand-int n)]
    [a (mod (exp a n) n)]))
```